# Get current data source of MXD file

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, data-source

I have a number of MXD files with data sources linking to an Enterprise geodatabase connection string.
I would like to update these connection strings with ArcPy programmatically to a new data source, much the same as if I was using "Set Data Sources" in ArcCatalog manually.

[image]

This works when I hardcode the current data source like this:

```
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"path/to/sde", path2newcon, False)
```

However, it would be better if I do not have to hard code the current connection but get it from the MXD file with ArcPy.

I can get the sources of each layer like this:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print "Layer: " + lyr.name + "  Source: " + lyr.dataSource
```

But I would like to get the connection string for the whole MXD file without any layer information.

How can I get the current data source with ArcPy?

Comment: Only Layer objects have data sources, so what you seek does not exist.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot – I implemented a per layer solution.